# Allow specific SharePoint 2010 group to access library

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

Changing gears. I have an infopath 2010 form that captures notes and restricts permission to the form based on user name. I do this by capturing the `CurrentUserUserName`. It works fine when the form gets emailed and they access and completes the infopath workflow. What I am having issues with is since they can contribute to the library, they also see the forms of other individuals. How can I restrict access to that specific group so when they go to the library, they can only see theirs.

Worthy of note is when I do allow view `[Me]`, to both the user on file and the sup - they need that so users can complete notes. I only have to prevent that group from seeing other forms in the library.

Answer (score 0):

Create separate workflow which would change permissions on SPListItem after certain action has completed (f.i. new form is filled out).
You can use Sharepoint Designer with custom workflow activities for that (http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/) or create it yourself using Visual Studio.